# Why is this Lucene Field Boost not preserving, or is there more to the story?

Tags: lucene

**Lucene 4.8.1** — I've tried to get this down to a very small example that just illustrates the question.

Below I insert a document that has a field with a boost value of 0.75.  Then I immediately pull that document back out, extract the field, and print it -- the boost shows 1.0.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, ParseException {

    // Put a document in with a field with a boost of 0.75
    Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_48);
    Directory directory = new RAMDirectory();
    IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory, new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_48, analyzer));

    Document doc = new Document();
    Field field = new Field("NAME", "VALUE", TextField.TYPE_STORED);
    field.setBoost(0.75f); // HERE'S THE CUSTOM BOOST //
    doc.add(field);
    writer.addDocument(doc);
    writer.close();


    // Find the field in the document and show it's boost
    Query query = new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_48, "NAME", analyzer).parse("VALUE");

    IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(DirectoryReader.open(directory));

    ScoreDoc[] hits = searcher.search(query, null, 1000).scoreDocs;
    Document hitDoc = searcher.doc(hits[0].doc);

    IndexableField iField = hitDoc.getFields().get(0);

    // Expecting 0.75, but it shows 1.0
    System.out.println(iField.name() + " = " + iField.stringValue() + " (boost " + iField.boost() + ")");
}
```

Now according to http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_1/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexableField.html the `boost()` method is supposed to show the field's boost value at *index* time, yet here's the output:

```
NAME = VALUE (boost 1.0)
```

I've checked with a debugger, at the time the document is added, that field has a boost of 0.75.

The catch appears to be with the words **at index time**, which is not the same as document insertion time.

Closer inspection suggests that the boost value goes through some normalization gyrations *before* it is stored in the index. Thus, the value could really and truly be 1.0 *in the index*.  Can someone confirm if my understanding is correct?

**The real question then is what happens when multiple values are stored for the same field with different boost values?**

```
Field f;
f = new Field("NAME", "AAA", TextField.TYPE_STORED); f(0.25); doc.add(f);
f = new Field("NAME", "BBB", TextField.TYPE_STORED); f(0.35); doc.add(f);
f = new Field("NAME", "CCC", TextField.TYPE_STORED); f(0.45); doc.add(f);
```

My tests show they still all come out with a boost value of 1.0.

```
NAME = VALUE (boost 1.0)
NAME = AAA (boost 1.0)
NAME = BBB (boost 1.0)
NAME = CCC (boost 1.0)
```

Perhaps the boost is part of the field and not its various values... trying another experiment to see if different field names will influence the boosts:

```
Field f;
f = new Field("XXX", "AAA", TextField.TYPE_STORED); f(0.25); doc.add(f);
f = new Field("YYY", "BBB", TextField.TYPE_STORED); f(0.35); doc.add(f);
f = new Field("ZZZ", "CCC", TextField.TYPE_STORED); f(0.45); doc.add(f);
```

My tests still show they all come out with a boost value of 1.0.

```
NAME = VALUE (boost 1.0)
XXX = AAA (boost 1.0)
YYY = BBB (boost 1.0)
ZZZ = CCC (boost 1.0)
```

I get similar results with more than one document, too.  Whatever I do, I always seem to get 1.0.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your boost is being stored correctly, you just can't retrieve the boost from the index.  To demonstrate this, running your sample code (thanks for the SSCCE!), I added to line to spit out an [`explain`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_8_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/IndexSearcher.html#explain%28org.apache.lucene.search.Query,%20int%29) (that line being:  `System.out.println(searcher.explain(query, 0).toString());`), we get:

```
0.23013961 = (MATCH) weight(NAME:value in 0) [DefaultSimilarity], result of:
  0.23013961 = fieldWeight in 0, product of:
    1.0 = tf(freq=1.0), with freq of:
      1.0 = termFreq=1.0
    0.30685282 = idf(docFreq=1, maxDocs=1)
    0.75 = fieldNorm(doc=0)

NAME = VALUE (boost 1.0)
```

You can see your boost in the second to last line, in the `fieldNorm`.

Which gives a vague hint as to why you can't get your boost back from the index.  It's stored in the fieldNorm.  That means your boost is combined with a `lengthNorm`, then compressed into a single byte, then stored along with the field in the index.  Since it's compressed into one byte, the compression is quite lossy (3 binary digits of precision), and there is no way to separate that value from the `lengthNorm`.  This may seem unimportant in this example, but if I change the value indexed to "VALUE AND STUFF", the overall `fieldNorm` becomes 0.5, due to the impact of the `lengthNorm`.

Also, a sidenote regarding your attempt to test with three different fields with the same name:  Fields with the same name added to the same document become part of the same field.  The product of all the boosts added in this way will be the final boost (in this case, 0.039375)

Comment: Brilliant explanation on what's happening under the hood, thank you. I'm glad to see the boost value is being taken into consideration -- I suspected it was.  I'm now just at a small loss as to why the documentation seems to go out of its way to claim one can get the boost value.  Great post @femtoRgon.